# Replacing render_to_response() with render() when no request is available

Tags: django

I'm updating my Django version and replacing this:

```
return render_to_response(template_name, {}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

with this:

```
return render(request, template_name, {})
```

However, sometimes I have no request:

```
return render_to_response(template_name, {})
```

But, render() requires a request variable. What can I use instead?

(Of course, I initially have a request, but a function calls a function, etc. and I'm not always passing request as a parameter. Hoping not to have to do that. )

EDIT: render_to_response() is deprecated. It wasn't working in Django 1.10, which is why I need to use something else. Every blog/forum/etc. says to use render(), but they don't cover this case.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you're trying to replace `render_to_response()` with `render()`, if `render_to_response()` is what you actually need...

Comment: render_to_response() is deprecated. I need to replace it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`render_to_response()` is not deprecated (yet). However, `context_instance` is and was [removed in 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/). To answer your question, you can use `render()` with a `request=None`:

```
return render(None, template_name)
```